# MIPS "main" declared global label but not defined

Tags: mips

This is a sample program for MIPS. I am using MARS 4.5, and I had enabled settings -> Initialize Program Counter to global "main" if defined. However, when i tried to assemble, it said that on the line .globl main, "main" declared global label but not defined. I am not sure how to fix it?

-------Macro definition-----

```
    # Macro : print_str
    # Usage: print_str(<address of the string>)
    .macro print_str($arg)
    li  $v0, 4     # System call code for print_str  
    la  $a0, $arg   # Address of the string to print
    syscall            # Print the string        
    .end_macro

    # Macro : print_int
    # Usage: print_int(<val>)
    .macro print_int($arg)
    li  $v0, 1     # System call code for print_int
    li  $a0, $arg  # Integer to print
    syscall            # Print the integer
    .end_macro

    # Macro : exit
    # Usage: exit
    .macro exit
    li  $v0, 10 
    syscall
    .end_macro
```

------Data Segment Definition----

```
.data
str: .asciiz "Enter="
```

----- Code Segment Definition ----

`.text
.globl main
Main:     print_str(str)
          print_int(54)
            exit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo. You used `Main:` instead of `main:`. It makes a difference.

*Side note:* It's nice to see a mips question that uses macros.